# Jquery hide and show for scroller

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do a vertical carousel, and am having issues with assigning classes to hide and show divs. Basically I have a bunch of div.wrapper with the first one assigned out of the box with a class of active. When I click on the top arrow, I want to remove that class, and have it "slide up", (I am using a class of hidden to accomplish this), and have the others "slide up" showing the next div.wrapper from under the wrapper. It works on the first click, but then stops.

```
$(".up-button").on("click", function(){
    $(".holder").first().removeClass('active').addClass('hide-    top').next().addClass('active');
  });

  $(".down-button").on("click", function(){
    $(".holder").first().addClass("active");
    $(".holder").siblings().removeClass('hidden');
  });
```

Comment: Read this before ask: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: show us a demo at jsfiddle.net

Comment: https://jsbin.com/sexuqo/edit?js,output

Comment: I think the problem is that I am targeting the .holder.first(), and adding the class of active, so when the 2nd .holder becomes active,  the .holder.first() is hidden, the 2nd .holder cannot pass or gain the classes.

Comment: I think I worked it out, not the best way I am sure, but it kind of works.